# Cannot successfully make here map requests using my api key

Tags: here-api

I cannot get a success response using the example code shown in the here documentation: https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/request-constructing.html

I created a Freemium account and generated two each of JS and REST api keys. Regardless of which key I try, I keep getting errors that seem to change with each attempt:

- Sometimes a 404
- Sometimes a 502
- Sometimes a 504
- Sometimes a 403 with a message I might understand if it happened every time:

  {
  Message: "User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: es:ESHttpGet"
  }
- Sometimes a 200 with a page not found error message from something called
  [Platform's Radar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6fxy.png)
- Sometimes a 302 that redirects to [a login for Kibana using a Live Nation account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTtFy.png)

For reference, a specific request from the documentation that I have been trying:
https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?apikey={API_KEY}&waypoint0=geo!52.5,13.4&waypoint1=geo!52.5,13.45&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled

I am really not sure what is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

On replicating the API call, it is resulting 200 every time. For reference find screenshot, please use correct APIkey[image]

Comment: It is working now after simply resubmitting my previous request without change. It works with any of my API keys. Since I am using the same API keys as previously, I guess there must have been something weird going on with my newly created account last week.